# Relate Foreign Key id fields without Migrations

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to figure out how to relate two id fields of two different models from an existing database without migration scripts.

I've pored over many, many different solutions; models.ForeignKey fields, models.ManyToOneRel fields, hyperlinked fields in the serializer, PrimaryKeyRelatedField in the serializer, every one seems to match a model to another model or another session and not match between two specific id fields in two different models.

This is the code I'm currently working with; its using [rsinger86 drf-flex-fields](https://github.com/rsinger86/drf-flex-fields) to allow designed expandable fields.

```
class Cats(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid3, editable=False)
    hatId = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, default=uuid.uuid3, editable=False)
    name = models.TextField()

class Hats(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid3, editable=False)
    name = models.TextField()


class CatsSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    hat = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cats
        fields = [
            'id',
            'hatId',
            'name'
        ]
        expandable_fields = {
            'hat': (HatsSerializer, {'source': 'hat', 'fields': ['name']})
        }

class HatsSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Hats
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name'
        ]
```

My hope is that I can eventually query a cat and use the expandable fields expand param to include that cats corresponding hat in the response.s

Comment: `manged = False` on the models would essentially work if the tables already exist and you just want to access the data in them. you put a `class Meta(object):` method on the model and use `db_table` and `managed = False` in your attributes. [See the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#managed)

Comment: @Hanny but will adding that automatically tie hatId in the Cats model to the id in the Hats model?

Comment: No, you'd have to make it a Foreign Key, at which point it would be related and tied together and keep you from needing any migrations - which was what I thought the original requirement was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar use case in my project and ForeignKey worked fine:

`hatId = models.ForeignKey(Hat, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='HatId')`

Django docs [ForeignKey.to_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field)

> By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object.

Comment: hmmm, is there any way to specify the field in the Hat model that its tied to or does models.ForeignKey just assume its id (or does it look for the Models primary key)?

Comment: It looks for promary key of foreign key Model.